# Angular material matcard dynamic inside material grid

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to display matCard dynamically using for loop with 3 columns and 3 rows totally 9 matcards using angular material .how to do that inside matGrid list. how to dipaly it dynamically inside grid and matcards . Can anyone help please

```
<mat-grid-list cols="3" rowHeight="1:0.7" >  <mat-grid-tile *ngFor ="let tile of Tiles">
    <mat-card class="card">
      <mat-card-header>
        <mat-icon class="front">home</mat-icon>
        <br />
        <mat-card-title>Pop</mat-card-title>
        <mat-icon class="corner">more_vert</mat-icon>
      </mat-card-header>
      <mat-divider></mat-divider>
      <mat-card-content class="content">
        <span class="num">7896</span>
        <br />
        Actual
        <br />
      </mat-card-content>

      <mat-divider></mat-divider>

      <mat-card-footer>
        <span>data:</span>
        <span style="padding-left: 40;"> 550,000</span>
        <br />
        <span> Accuracy: -6.5</span>
      </mat-card-footer>
    </mat-card>
  </mat-grid-tile>

</mat-grid-list>
```

Comment: Can you add Tiles object structure here?

Comment: i didn't add tiles object yet i was trying how to do that ? im new to angular material could you help

Answer (score 0):

I'm creating a CardList object which will iterate in mat-grid-tile. You can modify cardList object based on your requirement.

add this object in your .ts:

```
cardList = [
             {'cardTitle',: 'Card1 Title', 'cardSubTitle': 'CardSub', 'cardContent': 'Content for card 1', 'footer': 'footer for card 1'},
             {'cardTitle',: 'Card2 Title', 'cardSubTitle': 'Card2 sub title', 'cardContent': 'Card2 content ', 'footer': 'Card2 footer'},
             {'cardTitle',: 'Card3 Title', 'cardSubTitle': 'Card3 sub title', 'cardContent': 'Card3 content', 'footer': 'card3 footer'}

]
```

Now iterate in html:

```
<mat-grid-list cols="3" rowHeight="1:0.7" >
    <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let card of cardList">
     <mat-card>
      <mat-card-header>
          <mat-card-title>{{card.cardTitle}}</mat-card-tile>
          <mat-card-subtitle>{{card.cardSubTitle}}</mat-card-subtitle>
      </mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-content><p>{{card.cardContent}}</P</mat-card-content>
      <mat-card-footer>{{card.footer}}</mat-card-footer>
     </mat-card>
    </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```